# How to execute callback method after request finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, callback

callback does not execute after request finished.
Please give me suggestions.
How can I execute the callback method after request is finished successfully.
Thanks in advance.

```
async function sendSearchRequest(config, search_url, message, ambiente, callback){
      const options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://www.example.com',
        'headers': {
          ...
        },
        form: {...}
      };
      await request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
          consolel.log("Error!----------------------------", error);
        }
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
        const szPages = $('#divResultadosSuperior').find('table > tbody > tr > td:first-child').text();
        const szTexts = szPages.split(' ');
        const nPages = Math.ceil(szTexts[szTexts.length - 2] / 10);
        console.log("This is Number of Page: -----------", nPages);
        for(let i = 1; i <= nPages; i ++)
        {
          downloadPDFsOfPage(i, response.headers['set-cookie'][0], pdf_lists, search_url, message);
        }
        //await scrapPdf(response.body, response.headers['set-cookie'][0]);
      }).end(callback())
    }
```

Comment: Where does this `callback` come from? If it is a method, you never execute it. I'm assuming you want `callback()` for starters.

Comment: i see this code is a completely mess. where is the code for `request`. what is this code even supposed to do. can you show us more?

Comment: I have edited my code.